# What is the reason to use javascript frontend like React or Angular, for Java app?

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, spring, reactjs

I can imagine why to use React. For instance instead of Thymeleaf as React is 'V' in MVC stack. But Angular is a full stack framework with it's own security and own server side. Instead of using Spring Security with Thymeleaf there is a tricky business to line up Angular security with Java security. I read Dave Stayer post on integrating Spring with Angular and can't see a reason for combining two full stack approaches.

Comment: Angular is a framework for client side (browser side) of a web application which generally requires a server side like a Spring Web server. There is no server side in Angular framework (though some feature may be implemented in server like server side rendering). For the whole application, angulat is still the "V" in MVC stack.

Comment: to send an Ajax request to the server. We don’t want to go through Spring MVC controllers in order to get resources.

Comment: I do not know Angular,  but docs https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/concepts describe Model and Controller components, so are there mistakes in official documentation? Also, as I understand, to run Angular application there should be Node.js